# Paginar relaciones en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relaciones, paginación, modelorelacional

Estoy tieniendo un problema, ya que estoy relacionando tablas. El problema es que en la relaciones `hasMany` viene información muy excesiva.

Mi controlador:

```
$candidates = Job::where('enterprise_id', $enterprise_id)
        ->where('id', $jobid)
        ->with('candidates')
        ->first();
```

Modelos:

```
App\Job

public function candidates(){ //llamar candidates desde el with del controlador.
  //En este modelo necesito hacer paginación, ya que es donde se obtenien más resultados, en tabla muchos a muchos. 
  return $this->hasMany('App\JobCandidate')->with('candidate');
}


App\JobCandidate

public function candidate(){ //llamar candidate desde el modelo App\Job
   //Obtención de información de usuario.
   return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
 }
```

Como puedo hacer la paginación para `candidates` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería lo siguiente en tu controlador:

```
$job = Job::where('enterprise_id', $enterprise_id)
        ->where('id', $jobid)
        ->first();

$candidates = $job->candidates()->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Todo bien, el detalle que me retorna solo los `candidates` no me retorna la información del `job`.

Comment: Si, porque el job lo tienes en la variable $job, tienes que acceder a las propiedades desde esa variable.

Comment: Igual me funciona así, thanks!